# Replace Nulls in DataFrame with Max in Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Is there a way (more efficient than using a for loop) to replace all the nulls in a Pandas' DataFrame with the max value in its respective row.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"?  The time complexity of what you are trying to do cannot be improved from the basic implementation (loop through each row, compute max, fill nulls with max), as you need to look at every element at least once.

Comment: Generally with Pandas you can perform operations on the full frame at once using internal optimized functions that are faster than looping through the frame yourself.  For instance, df.mul(df2) is faster than looping through the frames simultaneously and doing the multiplication in python.  Similar to how numpy works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 0], 'b': [3, 0, 10], 'c':[0, 5, 34]})


   a   b   c
0  1   3   0
1  2   0   5
2  0  10  34
```

You can use `apply`, iterate over all rows and replace 0 by the maximal number of the row by using the `replace` function which gives you the expected output:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.replace(0, max(row)), axis=1)

    a   b   c
0   1   3   3
1   2   5   5
2  34  10  34
```

If you want to to replace `NaN` - which seemed to be your actual goal according to your comment - [you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058590/pandas-dataframe-replacing-nan-with-row-average)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, np.nan], 'b': [3, np.nan, 10], 'c':[np.nan, 5, 34]})

     a     b     c
0  1.0   3.0   NaN
1  2.0   NaN   5.0
2  NaN  10.0  34.0

df.T.fillna(df.max(axis=1)).T
```

yielding

```
      a     b     c
0   1.0   3.0   3.0
1   2.0   5.0   5.0
2  34.0  10.0  34.0
```

which might be more efficient (have not done the timings) than

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row.max()), axis=1)
```

Please note that

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(max(row)), axis=1)
```

does not work in each case as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47788361/1534017).

Comment: df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(max(row)), axis=1) did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: @rhaskett: It's been a while but please see my update.

Comment: interesting.  Luckily that code is long gone but that could have been a nasty bug.