# Why does max() sometimes return nan and sometimes ignores it?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, missing-data

This question is motivated by [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31708065/1534017) I gave a while ago.

Let's say I have a dataframe like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, np.nan], 'b': [3, np.nan, 10], 'c':[np.nan, 5, 34]})

     a     b     c
0  1.0   3.0   NaN
1  2.0   NaN   5.0
2  NaN  10.0  34.0
```

and I want to replace the `NaN` by the maximum of the row, [I can do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31708065/1534017)

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row.max()), axis=1)
```

which gives me the desired output

```
      a     b     c
0   1.0   3.0   3.0
1   2.0   5.0   5.0
2  34.0  10.0  34.0
```

When I, however, use

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(max(row)), axis=1)
```

for some reason it is replaced correctly only in two of three cases:

```
     a     b     c
0  1.0   3.0   3.0
1  2.0   5.0   5.0
2  NaN  10.0  34.0
```

Indeed, if I check by hand

```
max(df.iloc[0, :])
max(df.iloc[1, :])
max(df.iloc[2, :])
```

Then it prints

```
3.0
5.0
nan
```

When doing

```
df.iloc[0, :].max()
df.iloc[1, :].max()
df.iloc[2, :].max()
```

it prints the expected

```
3.0
5.0
34.0
```

My question is why `max()` fails in 1 of three cases but not in all 3. Why are the `NaN` sometimes ignored and sometimes not?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that in the third row the `nan` is the first entry, while in the other rows it comes later. So maybe it depends on the order in which `max` handles these values...

Comment: It is. I just checked, you don't even need pandas for this behaviour, you can just type `max([1,2,np.nan])` and `max([np.nan,2,3])`.

Comment: Here it may be a good place to remember that a [`np.nanmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html) exists too and it ignores `np.nan` altogether.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The reason is that `max` works by taking the first value as the "max seen so far", and then checking each other value to see if it is bigger than the max seen so far.  But `nan` is defined so that comparisons with it always return False --- that is, `nan > 1` is false but `1 > nan` is also false.

So if you start with `nan` as the first value in the array, every subsequent comparison will be check whether `some_other_value > nan`.  This will always be false, so `nan` will retain its position as "max seen so far".  On the other hand, if `nan` is not the first value, then when it is reached, the comparison `nan > max_so_far` will again be false.  But in this case that means the current "max seen so far" (which is not `nan`) will remain the max seen so far, so the nan will always be discarded.

Answer (score 8):

In the first case you are using the numpy `max` function, which is aware of how to handle `numpy.nan`.

In the second case you are using the builtin `max` function from python. This is not aware of how to handle `numpy.nan`. Presumably this effect is due to the fact that any comparison (>, <, == etc.) of `numpy.nan` with a float leads to False. An obvious way to implement `max` would be to iterate the iterable (the row in this case) and check if each value is larger than the previous, and store it as the maximum value if so. Since this larger than comparison will always be False when one of the compared values is `numpy.nan`, whether the recorded maximum is the number you want or `numpy.nan` depends entirely on whether the first value is `numpy.nan` or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the ordering of the elements in the list. First off, if you type

```
max([1, 2, np.nan])
```

The result is `2`, while

```
max([np.nan, 2, 3])
```

gives `np.nan`. The reason for this is that the `max` function goes through the values in the list one by one with a comparison like this:

```
if a > b
```

now if we look at what we get when comparing to `nan`, both `np.nan > 2` and `1 > np.nan` both give `False`, so in one case the running maximum is replaced with `nan` and in the other it is not.

Answer (score 1):

the two are different: max() vs df.max().

max(): python built-in function, it must be a non-empty iterable. Check here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

While pandas dataframe -- df.max(skipna=..), there is a parameter called skipna, the default value is True, which means the NA/null values are excluded. Check here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Comment: This would then still not explain why not always `nan` is returned but it is well explained in the other answers...

Answer (score 0):

If possibly it's inf issue, try to replace it as well as nan.

```
df[column] = df[column].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0.0)
df[column] = df[column].replace([np.nan, -np.nan], 0.0)
```