# Pandas, rolling max that ignores NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the max value in the past 3 rolling rows, ignoring `NaN` if I see them. I assumed that `skipna` would do that, but it doesn't. How can I ignore `NaN`, and also what is `skipna` supposed to do?

In this code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sales': [25, 20, 14]})
df['max'] = df['sales'].rolling(3).max(skipna=True)
print(df)
```

The last column is

```
   sales   max
0     25   NaN
1     20   NaN
2     14  25.0
```

But I want it to be

```
   sales   max
0     25  25.0
1     20  25.0
2     14  25.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`skipna=` has the default value of `True`, so adding it explicitly in your code does not have any effect.  If you were to set it to `False`, you would possibly get `NaN` as the max if you had `NaN`s in the original `sales` column.  There is a nice explanation of why that would happen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788524/9987623).

In your example, you are getting those `NaN`s in the first two rows because the `.rolling(3)` call tells pandas that if there is less than 3 values in the rolling window, they are to be set to `NaN`.  You can set the second parameter (`min_periods`) in the `.rolling()` call to require at least one value:

```
df['max'] = df['sales'].rolling(3,1).max()
df
#    sales   max
# 0     25  25.0
# 1     20  25.0
# 2     14  25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) with your command:

```
df['max'] = df['sales'].rolling(3).max().bfill()
```

Output:

```
   sales   max
0     25  25.0
1     20  25.0
2     14  25.0
```

Comment: I can use df.bfill(n-1).rolling(n).max() for my application. It doesn't fix the NaNs at the start of the array but my application has NaNs in the middle which were what I actually cared about.